# Loop in XML with Nokogiri and get a child element

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri

I'm struggling with a XML / GPX files where I need to grab some specific datas:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <trk>
    <trkseg>
      <trkde>
        <ele>78</ele>
        <time>2021-01-31T08:30:38.000Z</time>
        <extensions>
          <ns4:Extension>
            <ns4:hr>115</ns4:hr>
          </ns4:Extension>
        </extensions>
      </trkde>
      <trkde>
        <ele>77.8000030517578125</ele>
        <time>2021-01-31T08:30:40.000Z</time>
        <extensions>
          <ns4:Extension>
            <ns4:hr>115</ns4:hr>
          </ns4:Extension>
        </extensions>
      </trkde>
    </trkseg>
  </trk>
</gpx>
```

So far I'm trying to do this

```
doc.css("trkde").each do |trkde|
    unless trkde.css("time").blank?
        time = Time.zone.parse(trkde.css("time").text)
        hr = 0
        unless trkde.css("extensions").blank?
            puts trkde.css("ns4:Extension")
            hr = trkde.css("ns4:hr")
        end
        puts time.to_s + ":" + hr.to_s
    end
end
```

But I do not succeed in getting the value from `ns4:hr`

I read carefully https://nokogiri.org/tutorials/searching_a_xml_html_document.html but with my current understanding, I didn't succeed.

I did try to do `hr = track_point.xpath("ns4:hr")` but it doesn't work neither

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far I found this way

`hr = at_xpath('.//*[name()="ns4:hr"]').text.to_i`

But I feel it's not really elegant